# mod rewrite to remove text

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I use mod rewrite to omit /cgi-bin/ from this string?
http://www.website.com/cgi-bin/Gift/display_product_GFTSRR-19VS_Climb-Aboard.html

so that I can have this instead?
http://www.website.com/Gift/display_product_GFTSRR-19VS_Climb-Aboard.html

apparently we have duplicate pages depending on how one does a search.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/(Gift/.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: won't that take the cg-bin out of all my website?  I need it to stay in certain areas so that it will function properly.  I only want to remove it with this text    /cgi-bin/Gift/

Comment: oh ok got it, check the update now. Now it will only remove `/cgi-bin/Gift/...`

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.